# Python: How to connect to Bluestacks or another emulator by ppadb?

Tags: python, android-emulator, adb, bluestacks

I'm trying to simulate simple gestures like tap or swipe in BlueStacks emulator by using Python and PPADB. The problem is when I'm trying to connect.

```
Client(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
```

There is no devices. Emulator have address:

[image]

But when I try to connect to it by PPADB, then nothing happened and terminal stops work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66342834/able-to-connect-adb-to-bluestacks-but-not-ppadb-to-bluestacks) is the same ask.

I found working application where someone solved this problem but i dont understand what he exactly did.

Can someone check it and write simple code in one file?

[Here](https://github.com/Dylan-Zheng/Rise-of-Kingdoms-Bot) is a link to this app and code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

BlueStacks uses port 5037 for ADB. This means that

adb = Client(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555)

should instead be

adb = Client(host='127.0.0.1', port=5037)

Comment: yes, but as i said when im connecting like this i cand find device

Answer (score -1):

As you see in the link you mentioned, this person has an adb folder somewhere, where he runs `adb.exe` and starts the daemon, so the adb server runs in the localhost `127.0.0.1` on the port 5037 which is the default, so I suggest you try running `subprocess.run("/path/to/adb.exe","start-server")` and check again